# Min max inequality for dependent matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Consider the positive semidefinite matrix

$R(x)\geq0$, $\forall x\in\mathbb R^n$.

Furthermore, consider the pos. semidefinite matrix $A\geq0$. From the min-max theorem it is known that

$\lambda_{\min}x^2\leq x^TAx\leq\lambda_{\max}x^2$, where $\lambda_{\min/\max}$ is the minimum/maximum eigenvalue of $A$.

Does the min-max theorem also hold for

$x^TR(x)x$   ?

If $R(x)$ is bounded, is it correct that

$k_1I\leq R(x)\leq k_2 I$,

where $I$ is the identity matrix?

Comment: It is not clear what exactly $R$ is. Are you saying that for each $x  \in \Bbb R^n$, $R(x)$ is a positive semidefinite matrix?

Comment: Also, are you asking whether
$$
\lambda_{\min}(R(x))x^2 \leq x^TR(x)x \leq \lambda_{\min}(R(x))x^2
$$
holds for all $x$, or are there some *constants* (independent of $x$) that are meant to go on the right and left sides?

Comment: @BenGrossmann To your first comment: yes exactly

Comment: @BenGrossmann Actually, both would be interesting